# DataView.Sort not working despite using datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting

I have a dataTable, which then I stored into the DataView for sorting purposes. The sorting is custom based on the fieldname.

First, I add additional column using

```
dt.Columns.Add("Sorting", typeof(int));
```

After that, I run foreach loop and check using switch to determine the sorting number for each row in data table. For example, inside column named "Priority", there are 4 different choices either "Extremely High", "High", "Medium", "Low".

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string Priority = dr["Priority"].ToString();
    switch (Priority)
    {
            case "Extremely High": dr["Sorting"] = 1; break;
            case "High": dr["Sorting"] = 2; break;
            case "Medium": dr["Sorting"] = 3; break;
            case "Low": dr["Sorting"] = 4; break;
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    dr.SetModified();
}
```

So, I tried to sort using DataSort, but it isn't working in the chart. This is my code:

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "Sorting";
dt = dv.ToTable();

ChartStatus.DataSource = dt;
ChartStatus.DataBindCrossTable(dt.DefaultView, "Status", "Priority", "value", "");
ChartStatus.DataManipulator.GroupByAxisLabel("SUM", "*");
ChartStatus.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
```

The reason I want to sort the data before binding because I want the chart to display the value with higher priority first. Let say my bar chart has 4 segments in y-axis. I want that axis to sort by priority, rather than sort alphabetically.

Comment: Easier to sort DataTable : dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string.("Sorting"))

Comment: I had replace the code but still not working. Perhaps this only works in datatable but not in the chart?

Comment: You need to add column for each type dt.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(int));

Comment: But priority is in the string value. Like "High", "Low", etc. If I change to int, the coding won't work.

Comment: Then make it type string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why should I add column named Priority? Because I have assigned the Priority value as I retrieved from the database. The table already has column name Priority which consists of "High", "Low", etc.

Comment: The code isn't posted where you retrieve data from the database.  I do not know what columns are in the database.  Normally you would create an array like string[] priority = {"Extremely High", "High", "Medium", "Low"};  The sort using IndexOf : dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => priority.IndexOf(x.Field<string.("Priority")))